# About homology 3-spheres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $Y, Y_0, Y_1$ be homology 3-spheres (over $\mathbb Z$).

*Fact* (Poincaré-Perelman) : if $\pi_1(Y)=1$, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$.

Question : does $\pi_1(Y_0)=\pi_1(Y_1)$ implies $Y_0$ homeomorphic to $Y_1$ ?

If not, do you have a counter-example ?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211160/homology-spheres-and-fundamental-group

Comment: I got there by googling "homology spheres with the same fundamental group"...

Comment: Specifically, if they are irreducible, the answer is yes, while otherwise it is no.